# Flickering column width on this Tumblr page. Why?

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

Probably a simple thing to fix, but for some reason the content column on this Tumblr page has started to flicker on mouseover, between full width and (presumably) the original width that the theme was programmed with. Can anyone see what CSS is causing it? We're going a bit mad here.

http://todayiwantedtoprogram.tumblr.com/

(And yes, the code is horrendous. You can blame, for the mostpart, the original theme creator!)

Thanks in advance, folks.

Comment: Why don't you debug by iteratively simplifying the CSS until the problem disappears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason there is a `:hover` event on your main document, line 151, that shifts the content area upon hover. Remove that and it should fix your issue.

snippet

```
#content-center .regular:hover {
background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/02ma0np/JRhl6y2ty/post-on.png) no-repeat;
padding-left: 35px;
margin-left: 15px;
width: 520px;
}
```

Comment: Ah! Looks like it's for the favourite heart to illuminate. No idea why it'd need a width change though. Thanks so much!!